# List bundle ID's only on servicemix

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I'm using ServiceMix and I was trying to list some bundles and retrieve only there bundle ID.
I'm trying to do the following:

> osgi:list | grep -i  | awk xxx

I tried to use awk but that's not provided in ServiceMix.
I also tried to use shell:exec like this:

> osgi:list | grep -i  | shell:exec `awk 'xxx'`

But that doesn't work either, maybe my approach is completely wrong.
Does anybody else have some experience how I could achieve my goal of only retrieving the id's of a bundle?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can always make use of Karaf's shell language (Works as of karaf 2.3.1)

```
bundles = $.context bundles ;
echo "Printing bundle information" ;
each ($bundles) {
    symbolicName = $it symbolicName ;
    bundleId = (($it bundleid) toString) ;
    echo "Symbolic name : " $symbolicName " Bundle Id : " $bundleId ;
}
```

When ran this will output something similiar to :

```
Symbolic name :  org.apache.felix.framework  Bundle Id :  0
Symbolic name :  org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn  Bundle Id :  1
Symbolic name :  org.ops4j.pax.url.wrap  Bundle Id :  2
Symbolic name :  org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-service  Bundle Id :  3
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is a sed/awk command. And the list command cannot only just show the bundle id.

You can log a JIRA ticket for an enhancement. Maybe for options to the list command to select what to list only (bundle id, bundle version, state etc.)
http://karaf.apache.org/index/community/support.html