# Can you run a script file within JBoss Fuse' Karaf Terminal?

Tags: jboss, terminal, jbossfuse, karaf

The Karaf* terminal allows some scripting of commands at the prompt. Eg:

`($.context bundles) | grep -i felix`

[I have seen threads that discuss running multi-line scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16014100/list-bundle-ids-only-on-servicemix), presumably contained in a file.

My question is simply: How does one run a karaf language script file from the terminal? For my application the script can be a local file.

Thanks Very Much

*: JBoss Fuse (6.1.0.rehat-379)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `shell:source` command like this:

Here is a sample script.

```
computer:karaf donald$ cat test.script  
bundle:list -t 0 | head
echo 'Hello world 1'
echo 'Hello world 2'
echo 'Hello world 3'
```

Here is how you would invoke it from karaf:

```
Cobalt:bin donald$ ./karaf 
        __ __                  ____      
       / //_/____ __________ _/ __/      
      / ,<  / __ `/ ___/ __ `/ /_        
     / /| |/ /_/ / /  / /_/ / __/        
    /_/ |_|\__,_/_/   \__,_/_/         

  Apache Karaf (3.0.2)

Hit '<tab>' for a list of available commands
and '[cmd] --help' for help on a specific command.
Hit '<ctrl-d>' or type 'system:shutdown' or 'logout' to shutdown Karaf.

karaf@root()> shell:exec pwd
/Users/donald/apache-karaf-3.0.2
karaf@root()> shell:exec ls
LICENSE
NOTICE
README
RELEASE-NOTES
bin
data
demos
deploy
etc
instances
lib
lock
system
test.script
karaf@root()> shell:source test.script
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 0
ID | State    | Lvl | Version         | Name                                                               
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0 | Active   |   0 | 4.2.1           | System Bundle                                                      
 1 | Active   |   5 | 2.2.0           | OPS4J Pax Url - aether:                                            
 2 | Active   |   5 | 2.2.0           | OPS4J Pax Url - wrap:                                              
 3 | Active   |   8 | 1.7.4           | OPS4J Pax Logging - API                                            
 4 | Active   |   8 | 1.7.4           | OPS4J Pax Logging - Service                                        
 5 | Active   |  10 | 3.0.2           | Apache Karaf :: Service :: Guard                                   
 6 | Active   |  10 | 1.8.0           | Apache Felix Configuration Admin Service                           
Hello world 1
Hello world 2
Hello world 3
karaf@root()>
```

Comment: Very nice example, I did have to chown the test.script to the user which started karaf, and the "bundle:list" command in the first line of the script is "osgi:list" in JBoss Fuse (6.1.0.rehat-379), but other than that, it does the trick! Thx.

Answer (score 1):

create a file and add all the fuse commands you want to run at one shot
.From the karaf use the command shell:source

[Reference](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.0/html/Console_Reference/files/Consolesource.html)